# Get person details in new google sign in Play Services 8.3

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to get a user's profile using the new Google Sign In API introduced in play services 8.3. Other than Display Name, Email and Id, I also need user's gender.

```
Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson()
```

is deprecated as per play services 8.3 and also returns null for me even though

```
mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API)
```

returns true.

```
GoogleSignInAccount.getGrantedScopes
```

returns

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
profile
email
openid
```

Google Developer Console doesn't show any hits on the Google+ API. I have placed the correct google-services.json file in app/ folder of application. I even generated the SHA1 fingerprint programatically to verify if I was using the correct keystore.

How can I get the person google+ profile data (gender, family name, given name etc.) using the new sign in API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** based on @Isabella Chen's comments below, for who does not want to use `getCurrentPerson` which is marked deprecated, you can start using [Google People API](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/announcing-people-api.html) instead, you can also see my another answer at the following S.O question:

> [Cannot get private birthday from Google Plus account although explicit request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962724/cannot-get-private-birthday-from-google-plus-account-although-explicit-request)

---

IMO, you can refer to the following code:

```
        // [START configure_signin]
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        // FOR PROFILE PICTURE:
        // Ref: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#getPhotoUrl%28%29
        // getPhotoUrl(): Gets the photo url of the signed in user.
        // Only non-null if requestProfile() is configured and user does have a Google+ profile picture.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .requestProfile()
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END configure_signin]

        // [START build_client]
        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();
        // [END build_client]
```

Then:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);

            Person person  = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);            
            Log.i(TAG, "Gender: " + person.getGender());
        }
    }
```

Logcat info:

```
11-20 09:06:35.431 31289-31289/com.example.googlesignindemo I/GoogleSignIn: Gender: 0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the first place. But getCurrentPerson still returns null and the developer console doesn't show any hits on the G+ API.

Comment: You can use my sample project in GitHub with your `google-services.json` https://github.com/ngocchung/googlesignindemo

Comment: I compared the whole code and finally realised there was a typo in application id in gradle :|  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Plus.API has been deprecated. See my posted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @IsabellaChen thanks, I see, I have also had an answer about People API at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962724/cannot-get-private-birthday-from-google-plus-account-although-explicit-request/37963101#37963101, there in the comments I also metioned `PeopleApi insile Plus, which is now deprecated` :)

Comment: @BNK Thanks for posting many helpful answers to developers to help them solve Google API integration issues. Yeah, I know the answer was posted last year when Plus.API was definitely the easiest way to get verbose profile info. However, as you can see from the deprecation notes, Google will stop return data even for existing OAuth grants via Plus.PeopleApi. So we hope developers can use the newest blessed approach to access people details and not impacted by the deprecation when time comes.

Comment: @BNK, Plus.PeopleApi has been deprecated as a whole, see Javadoc:https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Plus. In Sep, new sign-ins will not get circle data back; in 2017 Q1, even existing grants will get empty data back. Again, thanks for your consistent support on Google APIs and help you gave to the developer community. However, we should move people away from using any G+ API on Android (other than +1 / sharing widgets etc) and point them to newest replacement, general People API (only REST is available right now) instead. Thank you!

Comment: @IsabellaChen thank you much for your infomation and I agree with you about using newest replacements if available :). Can I ask a question, `In Sep, new sign-ins will not get circle data back; in 2017 Q1, even existing grants will get empty data back`, even if I use Play Services 8.3?

Comment: @BNK, yes, even if you use 8.3. Android API is a wrapper to the underlying REST API, REST deprecation notes will come soon

Comment: i cant find a Person and plus class in getting Detail of  user

Comment: I have this issue: Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. Any idea how to solve it??

Answer (score 18):

Plus.API has been deprecated. See deprecation notes below:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/api-deprecation

If you need profile information other than first / last / display name, email and profile picture url (which is already provided by the [Sign-in API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people)), please use the new [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/).

On Android, you can do this:

```
// Add dependencies
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
```

Then write sign-in code.

```
// Make sure your GoogleSignInOptions request profile & email
GoogleSignInOptions gso =
        new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
// Follow official doc to sign-in.
// https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in
```

Use People Api to retrieve detailed person info.

```
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

// On worker thread
GoogleAccountCredential credential =
         GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this, Scopes.PROFILE);
credential.setSelectedAccount(
        new Account(googleSignInAccount.getEmail(), "com.google"));
People service = new People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME /* whatever you like */) 
                .build();
// All the person details
Person meProfile = service.people().get("people/me").execute();
// e.g. Gender
List<Gender> genders = meProfile.getGenders();
String gender = null;
if (genders != null && genders.size() > 0) {
    gender = genders.get(0).getValue();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me how to automatically get updated information about Google's Deprecation Notes, for example, by email subcription?

Comment: @BNK Unfortunately, no subscription channel available. But usually, deprecation will be announced in Google Play services SDK release notes: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases. Also, now Android Studio will prompt you for Google Play services SDK update. If you always update, you will see strikethrough on deprecated APIs. And you can then refer to the Javadoc for more details. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages

Comment: How to use HTTPS instead of HTTP please? And should `GoogleAccountCredential credential =
         GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this, Collections.singletonList(Scopes.PROFILE));` be used in the new version?

Comment: "Make sure your GoogleSignInOptions request profile & email". So this means GoogleSignInOptions.Builder needs .requestEmail() AND .requestProfile() I guess?!

Comment: Yeah, or GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();  See also official doc: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth

Comment: I have this issue: Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. Any idea how to solve it??

Comment: @Coeus I don't believe it's related to the Google Play services SDK you link. You can try removing play-services-* dependencies and try again? There are many other StackOverflow posts talking about the conflict you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

For getting profile information google introduced the easiest way so far I think!

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
  String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
  String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
  String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
  String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
  String personId = acct.getId();
  Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
}
```