# How to integrate google+ sign in my android app?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-signin

Hello all actually i need to sign in people from google+ through my app now i read documentation on google where it isstated that

> To allow users to sign in, integrate Google Sign-In into your app. When you initialize the GoogleApiClient object, request the PLUS_LOGIN and PLUS_ME scopes

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(Plus.API)
.addScope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
.addScope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)
.build();
```

Now i am confused that whether should i use above code only or implement google sign-in first and after that in my onsuccess method write this code to fetch person's profile from google+. Also in above code Scopes.Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN was not working so i have used PLUS.PLUS_LOGIN google's docs is so old.

Now i have used above code but it is not signing in from google+ account only it shows a dialog that from which account i need to sign in but when i click on that account it doesn't do anything also **currently i am using google-sign integration see below code**

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();
```

**and everthing is working great but i need person's gender and his/her date of birth that's why i thought about using google+ but the problem is google+ integration is not working for me what should i do now** ??

If anyone know how to fetch person's gender or date of birth using any of the two google+ OR google sign-in api please tell me how can i do this it could really mean something for me.

Comment: Have you read https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating yet?

Comment: yes i have implemented google-signin from above link

Comment: Ok, so please read my answer at the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-can-i-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android/33906880#33906880, hope it helps!

Comment: provide email id I will send you demo

Comment: sudhanshug09atgmail.com

Comment: Bad idea to personal share e-mail on a public place which will be indexed by search engines. At least make '@' to 'at'

Comment: pls tell me when u send the demo ok

Comment: In my above comment's link, you will see my GitHub sample code

Comment: This is the official sample link:

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Because you have said your current app works well with Google Sign-in already, so in order to get Google+ profile information such as Gender, Birthday..., first of all, **make sure you have created Google+ profile for your Google account**. Then you can update your app with the following codes. Please pay attention that I use `.requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))` at `GoogleSignInOptions`, not at `mGoogleApiClient`.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)             
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

and

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();
```

Then

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);

                // G+
            Person person  = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (person != null){
                    Log.i(TAG, "--------------------------------");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Display Name: " + person.getDisplayName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Gender: " + person.getGender());
                    Log.i(TAG, "AboutMe: " + person.getAboutMe());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Birthday: " + person.getBirthday());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Current Location: " + person.getCurrentLocation());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Language: " + person.getLanguage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside `build.gradle` file

```
// Dependency for Google Sign-In
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
```

*P/S: if Google+ profile has been created but after the time you add Google account in your device, you need to delete that existing Google account from your device, then re-add. When you run your app again, the message asking you allow/deny to access Google+ will be displayed. And of course, you must click Allow.*

Hope this helps and is clear for you!

Comment: Actually Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) is returning null is it working for your case because in my case i am getting data from google-sign in like display name and email but i am not able to fetch google+ data i think something you are missing in the code or i am doing something wrong, i am really very greatful to you and all of you for such tremendous response, but still google+ is not working hope there is some error that i will be fixed

Comment: also i have added gogle-services.json also if google-sign is working than i dont think there is some eroor on that part the error is somewhere else ??

Comment: Try uninstall the app from your phone/emulator, perhaps because of existing cache. Then, reinstall the app. Moreover, you can try with a new google account which having google+ profile already.

Comment: Ok, please upload your new project to github/google drive... so that I can check more.

Comment: https://github.com/sudhanshugaur4/googleplussignin/blob/master/README.md se my code here also i dont know how to add a file in github repostory so pls dont mind that ??

Comment: Can you zip your full project, then upload to google drive/one drive/dropbox or not?

Comment: sorry but i can only add this file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8i7-NXVXgr-YU9HY08wTjdOOEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When your app run, any logcat or error message displayed or not?

Comment: Login to console.developers.google.com with the Google account used to create the project
Look at API Manager - Enabled APIs check if Google+ API enabled or not

Comment: If you found Google+API disabled, enable it, then perhaps you should log-out then log-in again at console.developers.google.com. Then, uninstall the app in your phone, re-install it and check. Pls tell me if the screen asking allow/deny access Google profile appear or not

Comment: logcat dont show any error its just Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) returns null

Comment: bdw can you please have a relook at your code may be you are mssing something ??

Comment: also my dependencies are in this order does it matter or not ??           compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'

Comment: When you run your app, a screen asking allow/deny access Google+ profile appeared or not?

Comment: yes it appeared but after it i get all information from google sign in not of google+

Comment: You can try using my project, but need update application id as the same as package name when you create google-services.json file

Answer (score 0):

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814103/get-person-details-in-new-google-sign-in-play-services-8-3) is what you are lookin for.it clearly explains how to get user info. hope this answers your question.

Comment: nah see beolw answer it is same and i am not getting gender and date of birth of  person that is, i am only getting google information but not google+ accoutn info

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.google_plus;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    Button google_plus;

    String name,email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient =  new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();

        google_plus =(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_googleplus);

        google_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signInWithGplus();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to resolve any signin errors
     * */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }
        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            mConnectionResult = result;
            if (mSignInClicked) {
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                name = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+name+ "  ,  "+email,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                signOutFromGplus();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry we can't reach to your profile please signup with your email here...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-in into google
     * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    private void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}


/////////////////// android //////////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google_plus">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>


//////////gradle /////////////////////

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google_plus"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the code


  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener { private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(); private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007; private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient; private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog; private Button btnSignIn; private Button btnSignOut; private LinearLayout llProfileLayout; private ImageView imgProfilePic; private TextView txtName, txtEmail; @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login); btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout); imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic); txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name); txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email); btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this); btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this); GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build(); mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build(); } private void signIn() { Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient); startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN); } private void signOut() { Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() { @Override public void onResult(Status status) { updateUI(false); } }); } private void revokeAccess() { Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() { @Override public void onResult(Status status) { updateUI(false); } }); } private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) { Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess()); if (result.isSuccess()) { /* Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.*/ GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
    Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

    String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
    String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
    String email = acct.getEmail();


    Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
            + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

    txtName.setText(personName);
    txtEmail.setText(email);
    ;
} else {

    updateUI(false);
}
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.login:
                signIn();
                break;

            case R.id.logout:
                signOut();
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+result);
            handleSignInResult(result);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }



    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
}
```