# Get first and last name of user using Google SignIn API in Android

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm developing app and using Google SignIn. In the iOS Api, I can get the first name and last name like this:

```
let GoogleUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser
let firstName = googleAccount.profile.givenName
let lastName = googleAccount.profile.familyName
```

But in the Android API, I found only `getDisplayName()` that returns the full name of the user in one String. I can't find any method that returns only the first or the last name.

[The Google SignIn API for Android site](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

In android also have,

```
getFamilyName()
getGivenName()
```

Refer this,

> [com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person.Name](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.Name#public-method-summary)

Comment: This solution works (Using the solution here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33817833/4723532) but this solution uses Google Plus API and not the regular Google SignIn API for Android. The iOS version of the Google SignIn API has the option for first name and last name separated, so I want to do it the same in Android without additional API. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Okay . Mark as answer if it helps you

Comment: @AvivAbramovich: if you don't want to use Plus API, try https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library or http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html to see if they can help or not

Answer (score 1):

//After the signing we are calling this function
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

```
    //If the login succeed
    if (result.isSuccess()) {

        signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Getting google account
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        String name=acct.getDisplayName();

        String email=acct.getEmail();

        Log.d("namegoogle",name);
        Log.d("emailgoogle",email);
        edit_signin_emailid.setText(email);

        String fullname = acct.getDisplayName();
        String[] parts = fullname.split("\\s+");
        Log.d("Length-->",""+parts.length);
        if(parts.length==2) {
            String firstname = parts[0];
            String lastname = parts[1];
            Log.d("First-->", "" + firstname);
            Log.d("Last-->", "" + lastname);
            AppController.setStringPref("firstnamebook", firstname);
            AppController.setStringPref("lastnamebook", lastname);

            Log.d("FirstApp", "" + AppController.getStringPref("firstnamebook"));
            Log.d("LastApp", "" + AppController.getStringPref("lastnamebook"));
        }
        else if(parts.length==3){
            String firstname = parts[0];
            String middlename = parts[1];
            String lastname = parts[2];
            Log.d("First-->", "" + firstname);
            Log.d("Last-->", "" + lastname);
            AppController.setStringPref("firstnamebook", firstname);
            AppController.setStringPref("lastnamebook", lastname);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String fullname = "Sathish Kumar Jeyasankar";
String[] parts = fullname.split("\\s+");
String firstname = parts[0]; // Sathish
String middlename = parts[1]; //  Kumar
String lastname = parts[2]; //  Jeyasankar
```

Comment: Assume username like "Sathish Kumar Jeyasankar" means?. how it's works?

Comment: What about "Usama bin laden"? "bin laden" is the last name ("bin" is not a middle name). This is varies from language to language, so I don't like these "low level" solutions...

Comment: You said you wanted first or last name only. Thank you