# How to retrieve google plus profile from playservice 11.0.4

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

The older methods to retrieve the profile data is deprecated. SO been trying from a couple of days to retrieve age, gender and location info after a google success signin.
I have tried:

[How to get profile like gender from google signin in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-to-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android)

[Get person details in new google sign in Play Services 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814103/get-person-details-in-new-google-sign-in-play-services-8-3/39171650#39171650)

and other similar ones

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your google service. on project gradle

`'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'`

then update your google account login API on app gradle

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
```