# Getting birthday within the app, after signing in with Google

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I followed the official document for implementing sing-in with Google. It was not difficult, but the official document stopped at getting the basic information such as name or e-mail. I need to get birthday.

So, when creating the option, I added this:

```
.requestScopes(Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read"))
```

Since the official document stopped there I could not get how to get birthday. So I have searched the web and found a method using a plain HTTP GET request to `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me`. (Or is this covered by the Google Play Services API?)

But the method needs the access token, which was not included in the `GoogleSignInAccount` which was returned after signing in. There was an example for getting the access ID by creating an OAuth server ID and then use `getServerAuthCode()` to get the access token, but that is complicated and it is not done on a server, it is done inside the app, right after singing in.

In this case, do I have to create an OAuth server ID, and use the access token to get the birthday?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of Google searching, I have found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39171650/455796). Before finding this, I found an example of using Plus.API, but this answer said it was deprecated. The funny thing is, now even this answer is outdated and does not work. I had to search a lot more to fix it. If only Google's sign-in document page included an example of getting additional data other than the default fields, all these miseries could have been avoided.

Anyways, this is the code that worked for me.

```
First, sign in with Google according to the official documentation.
Then,

val HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
val JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

inner class DamnTask(var email:String) :AsyncTask<Unit,Unit,Unit>()
{
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Unit?)
    {
        var credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context,
                Collections.singletonList(Scopes.PROFILE));
        credential.selectedAccount = Account(email, "com.google");

        var service = People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("MyApp")
                .build();

        var me = service.people().get("people/me")
                .setRequestMaskIncludeField("person.Birthdays")
                .execute();
        Log.d("damn", "Birthday " +me.birthdays.toString());
    }
}
```

To make it work, I had to add the following libraries to the dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
```

Also, I had to enable the "People" API in the project's settings. This needs to be done in the Google's web console. I forgot the URL, but if you do not enable it, the exception message will show the exact URL to enable it.

You can find more field names [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get).