# Google Signin request for age not working

Tags: android, oauth, token, google-signin

I am trying to login to google with Android, then I am sending the token to my server, and trying to access the data.

I would like to have access to the age range of the user, but seem to be unable.

Here is the Android code:

```
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .requestId()
            .requestIdToken(mView.getTarget().getString(R.string.google_server_client_id))
            .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.agerange.read"))
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
// options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mView.getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(mView.getTarget().getActivity(), new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: google signin");
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

And here is the output (Server side) after using the access token received by the Android app:

```
[azp] => 99415613(...)s.googleusercontent.com
   [aud] => 994156(...)nss.apps.googleusercontent.com
   [sub] => 100452979093996347493
   [email] => b(...)gmail.com
   [email_verified] => 1
   [exp] => 1520621452
   [iss] => https://accounts.google.com
   [iat] => 1520617852
   [name] => M(...)e
   [picture] => https://lh3(...)hoto.jpg
   [given_name] => M(...)
   [family_name] => A(...)
   [locale] => (...)
```

Where the hell did age range go to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Getting Profile Information](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people) page, it looks like GoogleSignInOptions does not directly return information about a [Person](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/java/latest/) in the response but rather `.requestProfile()` just provides additional information [Account](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount) object.

To get the information you want, you need to use the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/) which replaced the Plus API.

After you sign in with your original code you need to create a credential and use it with the People API:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(); //use some json factory of your choice

GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, Scopes.PROFILE);
//NOTE: You'll use the email returned by your sign in (or an Account object from the same)
credential.setSelectedAccount(new Account(email, "com.google"));

People service = new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("My Application").build();
//'me' resolves of course, to the account you chose
Person person = service.people().get("people/me").execute();
person.getAgeRange();
```

Note: A lot of credit for my understanding of this goes to [this blog article](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/people-api-android-tutorial-2/) and to [Isabella Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39171650/984830)s answer, so you might want to check those out too